# My crosstab query is not working when opening a DAO.Recordset

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, excel

I have a pretty simple query, just tested it on MSACCESS and it works, when using it in Excel VBA it crashes with an error. "Incorrect Syntax near Yearly PV. I might be missing something obvious. Here goes the VBA code:

```
StrQuery = "TRANSFORM Sum([Yearly Pv].[Original_Print_volume]) AS SumOfPrintvolume " & _
                "SELECT [Yearly Pv].[Press1] " & _
                "FROM [Yearly Pv] " & _
                "WHERE ((([Yearly Pv].[Year]) = 2016 Or ([Yearly Pv].[Year]) = 2017)) " & _
                "GROUP BY [Yearly Pv].[Press1] " & _
                "PIVOT [Yearly Pv].[Year];"
rst.Open StrQuery, cnn
```

The table is pretty simple, it contains 3 columns:
Press1, Original_Print_volume, Year.

Example Rows:

```
+---------+----------------------+------+
| Press1  | Monthly print volume | Year |
+---------+----------------------+------+
| ABCTEST |                10000 | 2016 |
| ABCTEST |                15000 | 2017 |
| DEFTEST |                 5000 | 2016 |
| DEFTEST |                 7500 | 2017 |
+---------+----------------------+------+
```

I want this to become:

```
+---------+-------+-------+
| Press1  | 2016  | 2017  |
+---------+-------+-------+
| ABCTEST | 10000 | 15000 |
| DEFTEST |  5000 |  7500 |
+---------+-------+-------+
```

ABCTEST are dynamic. The years I can hardcode.

**Edit:**

The rst.Open strquery, cnn works with all my other queries. it is a simple connection to a SQL Server database.

Comment: TRANSFORM is not valid in sql server. The same syntax from ACCESS does NOT work in any DBMS. The syntax is usually a bit different.

Comment: So what can I use instead of Transform?

Comment: Looks like you probably want to use PIVOT. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: But with Pivot I must indicate the rows and columns right? My code is dynamic, the columns will be fixed, but the [Press1] field is variable. any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I can't tell you because it is not clear what you are trying to do here. My guess is this is pretty straight forward but without something to work with it is impossible. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Is it better now? Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you can use PIVOT in sql server or you can use conditional aggregation (aka crosstab).

Notice how I turned your data into an easily consumable table? You should consider something similar for future posts. Makes it really easy for those helping.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Press1 varchar(10)
    , MonthlyVolume int
    , Year int
)

insert @Something values
('ABCTEST', 10000, 2016)
,('ABCTEST', 15000, 2017)
,('DEFTEST', 5000, 2016)
,('DEFTEST', 7500, 2017)

select Press1
    , [2016] = max(case when Year = 2016 then MonthlyVolume end)
    , [2017] = max(case when Year = 2017 then MonthlyVolume end)
from @Something
group by Press1
```

OUTPUT:

```
Press1  2016    2017
ABCTEST 10000   15000
DEFTEST 5000    7500
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Regarding the Years, I could hypothetically do a loop in VBA that would generate those rows to make it for dynamic years. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can use dynamic sql to generate the columns based on the data found in the table. If you do this in VBA you would have to query each year found which is not going to perform very well. I would prefer to do this in a stored procedure and not have any of the logic be in VBA.